# XDocument: get the first child element of type 'a' or 'b'

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

I have the below markup, in which each `item` element *must* contain exactly one `a`, `b`, `c`, or `d` element, and in addition can contain a variety of additional elements. The position of the required (`a`, `b`... type) elements is not certain.

```
<root>
  <item>
    <a>...</a>
    ...
  <item>

  <item>
    ...
    <d>...</d>
  <item>

  <item>
    <c>...</c>
  <item>

  ...
</root>
```

Using [XDocument](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument(v=vs.110).aspx), how can I express the following:

> Return the first child element of type `a`, `b`, `c`, or `d`.

I'm currently using a chain of if-else statements, but this blasphemy must go; it seems way too much for such a seemingly easy task:

```
foreach (XElement xItem in xmlDoc.Root.Elements("item"))
{
    if (xItem.Element("a") != null)
    {
        // element <a>...</a> found
    }
    else if (xItem.Element("b") != null)
    {
        // element <b>...</b> found
    }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand it, you still want to keep the for loop since you want to do something about the element relative to its containing `Item`, but you want to make the code the gets the first `a`,`b`,`c`, or `d` element cleaner.

Here is how you can do it:

```
var names = new XName[] { "a", "b", "c", "d" };

foreach (XElement xItem in xmlDoc.Root.Elements("item"))
{
    var element = xItem.Elements().FirstOrDefault(x => names.Contains(x.Name));
    //Do something with element
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `FirstOrDefault` for this task:

```
var firstAorBorCorD = xmlDoc.Root
    .Elements("item")
    .Select(xItem =>
        xItem.Elements().FirstOrDefault(sub =>
            sub.Name == "a" || sub.Name == "b" || sub.Name == "c" || sub.Name == "d"
        )
    );
```

This will produce a sequence of first children of type {a, b, c, d} for each `item`. If a particular item has no children of desired type, its corresponding entry in the list would be `null`.

Answer (score 1):

Well it sounds like you might want something like:

```
var names = new XName[] { "a", "b", "c", "d" };
var element = xmlDoc.Root
                    .Elements("item")
                    .Elements()
                    .FirstOrDefault(x => names.Contains(x.Name));
```